# Pascal's Triangle - Finding nth line

Tags: java

Having issues with my code. It has to ask the user to enter a nth line, and print the line. The error is in line 62, when I remove the arrow it doesn't give a suggestion.

Using this:
[image]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PascalsTriangle {
  private int lineNumber, count;
  private int[] num;

  public PascalsTriangle() {
    lineNumber = 1;
  }

  public PascalsTriangle(int n) {
    set(n);
  }

  public void set(int n) {
    if (n < 1)
      lineNumber = n;
  }

  public int get() {
    return lineNumber;
  }

  private void pascal(int[] row) {
    if (count >= lineNumber)
      return;
    num = new int [row.length+1];
    num[0] = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < row.length; i++)
      num[i] = row[i-1] + row[i];
    num[row.length] = 1;
    count++;
    pascal(num);
    return;
  }

  public int[] output() {
    count = 1;
    num = new int[count];
    return num;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, num;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the Nth number: ");

    num = scan.nextInt();
    PascalsTriangle t = new PascalsTriangle(num);
    int[] result = t.output();
    System.out.println("Line" + t.get());
    for (i = 0; < result.length; i++)
      System.out.println(result[i] + " ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you point out the exact line that fails? You said it was on line 62, but line numbers don't appear on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The for-loop on line 62 should be:

```
for(i=0; i < result.length ; i++){
```

The logic ill leave up to you because this seems to be a homework assignment.